# Orthogonal random variables - an exercise

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, analysis, orthonormal

Long time ago, I was given the following exercise in a class.

Let $$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n, \dots,$$
be a sequence of random variables, such  that $\mathbb{E}X_iX_j =0$
for $i\not=j$ and $\mathbb{E}X_i^2 =1$ for all $i$. Let
$$a_1,a_2,\dots, a_N,$$ be a sequence of real numbers. Prove that
for
$$Y_N:= \ \max_{i\le N} \Big|\sum_{k=1}^{i}a_k X_k\Big|,$$
we have
$$\mathbb{E}Y_N^2 \ \le \ O(\log^2N)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k^2.$$
Unfortunately, I never learned how to solve this problem. It looks elementary, but I don't know how to attack it. Does anybody know how to do it? I will be grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know either, but i will try to start.

Taking $N$ as you gave it, there exists an index $\overline{i}$ such that

$$\mathbb{E}Y_N^2=\mathbb{E}\bigl{\{}\sum_{k=1}^{\overline{i}}a_kX_k \bigr{\}}^2\le\mathbb{E}\bigl{\{}\sum_{k=1}^{\overline{i}}X_k \bigr{\}}^2\biggl{\{}\sum_{k=1}^{\overline{i}}a_k\biggr{\}}^2\le \mathbb{E}\bigl{\{}\sum_{k=1}^{\overline{i}}X_k \bigr{\}}^2\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k^2$$
and now it would be convenient to show that
$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}\bigl{\{}\sum_{k=1}^{\overline{i}}X_k \bigr{\}}^2}{log^2(N)}=0$$

Anyways, this is merely a way for you to be inspired, nothing else.

Comment: No, there does not exist $i$ with that property. Unless you mean for $i$ to be a random variable. Regarding the last limit, note that $\Bbb E(\sum_{k=1}^NX_k)^2 = N$.

Comment: Regarding the index $\overline{i}$, i got it from the fact that it is the index for witch the $Y_N$ is effectively the $\max$ of the positive sum. So that limit is not equal to zero is what you are saying, i know that it is not a proof, it's a mix of wrong steps leading to a wrong thesys, beautiful.